# Returning two variables in two different divs using Jquery and 1 php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to return the value of two variables in two different divs using Jquery and **1 php file**?

**PHP**

```
<?php
$variable1 = "10";
$Variable2 = "20";
echo $variable1;
echo $variable2;
?>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#id").on("change", function() {
var $form = $("#Form");
var method = $form.attr("method") ? $form.attr("method").toUpperCase() : "GET";
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    type: method,
    success: function(data){
          $('#Target1').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

I want to show the value of **$variable1** in `<div id="Target1"></div>` and **$variable2** in `<div id="Target2"></div>`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Don't do  `echo` then `echo` though because then the values will be concatenated (pretty much `echo 1; echo 2;` would send `12` (indecipherable). Separate with a comma (or another symbol), or send XML,  or send JSON. Then decompile sting in JS.

Comment: `$variable2 !== $Variable2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return your data in `JSON` format through your `PHP` file. Use `json_encode`.

Example:

```
<?php
$variable1 = "10";
$variable2 = "20";
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // specify that you are sending a json response
echo json_encode(array("var1" => $variable1, "var2" => $variable2)); // return a json
```

In your JavaScript file, data.var1 and data.var2 will be set.

Display them like this:

```
$('#Target1').text(data.var1);
$('#Target2').text(data.var2);
```

There are other formats that you could use, in general you can use either JSON or XML.

Comment: This will display an error and will not work: `$variable2 !== $Variable2`.

Comment: Thank you very much Pierre:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to call PHP page from an HTML page including the JQuery implementation. You have to put some params in GET or POST and read this params in PHP file. Example with GET:

```
<?php
$variable1 = "10";
$variable2 = "20";
if($_GET["name"]=="div1")
  echo $variable1;
else 
  echo $variable2;
?>
```

Comment: This will display an error and will not work: `$variable2 !== $Variable2`.